# bxslider with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, bxslider

I develope a webpart for sharepoint 2010 internet site that uses bxslider. when i use this web part in english pages it works while in arabic it renders the content but it flash and disappear when page load complete.

I use the following code:

```
 <div style="text-align:right;margin-right:6px;height:255px;width:310px;border: 1px #B8B8B8 solid;background-color:#F3F3F4;" >

    <div>

<div class="SpotTitle1">آخــر الاخــبار 
   <img id="go-next15" src="/_catalogs/masterpage/en-us/Preview Images/perv.png" width="20" height="18" align="left" />
   <img id="go-prev15" src="/_catalogs/masterpage/en-us/Preview Images/next.png" width="20" height="18" align="left"/>
</div>
<div id="slider15" style="liststyle: none;padding:0 !important;">
<div id="News1" runat="server" class="TitleLink"></div>
<div id="News2" runat="server" class="TitleLink">
</div></div> </div></div>
```

and on sharepoin masterpage i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){ 
    var slider15 = $('#slider15').bxSlider({
                           controls: false  
                   });

    $('#go-prev15').click(function(){  
            slider15.goToPreviousSlide();
            return false;  
    });
    $('#go-next15').click(function(){  
            slider15.goToNextSlide(); 
                return false; 
    });

}); 
</script>
```

any one have idea about what i can do to let it appear after page load.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the ( en-us ) in 
src="/_catalogs/masterpage/en-us/Preview Images/perv.png"

try put the images in PublishingImages Folder

Comment: that is not the problem, images rendered fine. i tried to make the direction ltr on slider it works but without animation